# Using multiple buttons on same function that redirects to different functions

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

So..i'm having this problem for couple of days not knowing how to do this,and i need help.

I have multiple buttons and clicking all of them is redirecting me to same function and from that function is going to another function specified for that button. 
Any idea how can i go true couple of functions knowing which button is clicked?
example :

```
 <html>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="1">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="2">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" id="3">Button1</button>

<script>

function myFunction()
{
   var x=0;

    if (button 1){
     x=1;
     myFunction1(x);}

   if (button 2){
    x=2;
    myFunction2(x);}

    if (button 3){
     x=3;
     myFunction3(x);}

     ...
    myFunction3(x){
    alert(x);
}
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: i'll try it with switch/case and then make one variable for every button in case to past to other functions?
 i have approximately 10 different functions and some of them are being used by every button some with couple different buttons

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Easiest way would probably be to pass in the element into the function:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="1">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="2">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="3">Button1</button>

function myFunction(elem) {
    alert(elem.id);
}
```

No need to think about event arguments or anything like that.

Answer (score 18):

At its simplest:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="1">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="2">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(this)" id="3">Button1</button>

function myFunction (button) {
    var x = button.id;
    switch (x) {
        case '1':
            myFunction1(x);
            break;
        case '2':
            myFunction2(x);
            break;
        case '3':
            myFunction3(x);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CYGGD/3/).

Though I'd amend the above to use unobtrusive JavaScript, moving the JavaScript event-handling from the elements' HTML mark-up:

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
for (var i = 0, len = buttons.length; i < len; i++) {
    buttons[i].onclick = function (){
        myFunction (this);
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CYGGD/4/).

Or, to make it even easier (and add the event-handling to one element, rather than three):

```
function myFunction (event) {
    var x = event.target.id;
    console.log(event.target, x);
    switch (x) {
        case '1':
            myFunction1(x);
            break;
        case '2':
            myFunction2(x);
            break;
        case '3':
            myFunction3(x);
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

var parent = document.getElementById('parentElementID');
parent.addEventListener('click', myFunction);
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/CYGGD/2/).

Incidentally, while it's valid (under HTML 5, *not* under HTML 4) to have an `id` that starts with a numeric character (0-9), in CSS it's difficult to target those elements (leading numeric characters require escaping, in any one of various ways); so it's still advisable to have a predictable alphabetic prefix to those `id`s.

References:

- [`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/elemento.addEventListener).
- [`for () {...}` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for).`
- [`switch () {...}` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

Comment: +1 pretty much what I was thinking but you typed faster.  Also like the suggestion to get the code out of the markup. Yes, make the id alphanumeric, not just numeric.

Answer (score 1):

IF you can change the HTML, try:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(1)" id="1">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(2)" id="2">Button1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(3)" id="3">Button1</button>
```

And change your JS to:

```
function myFunction(bnum)
{
   var x=0;

    if (bnum == 1){
     x=1;
     myFunction1(x);}

   if (bnum == 2){
    x=2;
    myFunction2(x);}

    if (bnum == 3){
     x=3;
     myFunction3(x);}
}
```

It's a bit nicer in a switch:

```
function myFunction(bnum)
{
   var x=0;
   switch (bnum) {
      case 1:
          x = 1;
          myFunction1(x);
      break;
      case 2:
          x = 2;
          myFunction1(x);
      break;
      case 3:
          x = 3;
          myFunction1(x);
      break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could put

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button"),
    len = button.length,
    i;
function click(){
  alert(this.id);
}
for(i=0;i<len;i+=1){
  button[i].onclick=click;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="1">Button1</button>
<button type="button" id="2">Button1</button>
<button type="button" id="3">Button1</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

i just sent a number as a reference..

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction(1)">Button1</button>
```

and then at the function

```
function whatever(v){
  if (v == 1){
    //dot stuff..
  }
}
```