# check previous active link after clicking the link in menu bar, jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add class in link if previous link was home link i am trying so hard but I am not getting the answer of it.
it is simple nav bar, if active link home then clicked link will be added a class..thats it

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    var prevLink = ??; // how can i get prevLink here
    if(prevLink == 'Home') {
        $(this).addClass("addext");
        $('ul li').removeClass("addext");
    }
});
```

how to check previous active link ?

Comment: show your html code please

Comment: Could you provide the html code for this?! Your question is still unclear!

Answer (score 1):

Not the complete answer, because of your missing html, but you should switch these two lines:

```
$(this).addClass("addext");
$('ul li').removeClass("addext");
```

To:

```
$('ul li').removeClass("addext");
$(this).addClass("addext");
```

Otherwise you set, and instant remove the class.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help:

```
var globalPrevLink = "";

$('#Home').onclick(function(){
    globalPrevLink = window.location.href; // this is clicked last time so remember it in globalPrevLink variable
});
```

Put above code somewhere in your js and change Home to whatever ID you have given to your home link tag.

then change your code as

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
    var prevLink = globalPrevLink; // globalPrevLink is assigned here
    if(prevLink == 'Home') { // change this also as accordingly, use console log
        $('ul li').removeClass("addext"); // switch as suggested in other comment
        $(this).addClass("addext");
    }
});
```

Comment: it should be automatically check the active link among the unordered list. if thet link is home link then next line will exicute..

Comment: I can give hint to you only but you'll have to find it by yourself

Comment: You should create a common method that should be called on each unordered list item clicked

Comment: use this link to know how you can call same function on different buttons
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410341/using-multiple-buttons-on-same-function-that-redirects-to-different-functions

Answer (score 0):

Use  `$('ul li.addext').text();` to get the li text which has addest class

```
$('ul li').click(function(){
        var prevLink = $('ul li.addext').text();
        if(prevLink == 'Home') {

             $('ul li').removeClass("addext");
            $(this).addClass("addext");

        }
    });
```