# How to automate instructions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wonder how can I automate and ease javascript code.
For example, I have got 3 buttons:

```
<button id="rock" class="pick" value="rock">rock</button>
<button id="paper" class="pick" value="paper">paper</button>
<button id="scissors" class="pick" value="scissors">scissors</button>
```

And I select these elements 3 times. So my question is how can I make it in just one instruction or function?

```
var userInput = '';

document.getElementById('rock').onclick = function() {
        userInput = 'rock';
}

document.getElementById('paper').onclick = function() {
        userInput = 'paper';
}

document.getElementById('scissors').onclick = function() {
        userInput = 'scissors';
}
```

I just wonder if I can make something like this:

```
document.getElementById(element).onclick = function() {
        userInput = element.value;
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410341/using-multiple-buttons-on-same-function-that-redirects-to-different-functions/18410383 and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18160/different-way-of-writing-multiple-click-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. As a matter of fact you could have multiple elements, with an added event listener to them, that will give you their added `value`. Let's say you have 3 items, all with class `gameCommands`. Then you'd do something like this:

```
const commands = document.querySelectorAll(".gameCommands")
const userInput;
commands.forEach(command => command.addEventListener("click", getValue)

function getValue(){
  // THIS represents the element from which we call the function in this case.
  userInput = this.value;
}
```

Comment: Nice, elegant, generalised solution. +1 _[ Although I'm not sure why you invented your own class name when the OP provided you with theirs, namely `".pick"`. ]_

Comment: @CJK Oops, didn't even saw that he already had put classes in there, my bad :D Anyways, I hope he gets the point from the answer and that he found it helpful :D

Comment: Be careful with [*NodeList.forEach*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), it hasn't been added to the [*DOM Living Standard*](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-nodelist) yet and is not supported everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('pick');

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].onclick = function() { userInput = this.value; } 
}
```

Comment: Yes, that was something I was thinking of. Thank you so much.